# What is the reason that a subscription is not being invoked?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am trying that when creating a record the user is notified of the success or failure of the action

To this end I have prepared the following:

post.actions.ts

```
export const PostActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Create post component',
  events: {
    'Create post': props<{ payload: CreatePostModel }>(),
    'Successful post creation': emptyProps(),
    'Failed post creation': props<{ payload: any }>(),
  },
});
```

post.effects.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ContentEffects {
  addContent$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PostActions.createPost),
      exhaustMap((action) =>
        this.postService.save(action.payload).pipe(
          map(
            (payload) => PostActions.successfulPostCreation(),
            catchError((error) =>
              of(PostActions.failedPostCreation({ payload: error }))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private readonly postService: PostService,
    private readonly actions$: Actions
  ) {}
}
```

post.reducer.ts

```
export interface PostState {
  success: string;
  error: any;
}

export const initialState: PostState = { success: '', error: undefined };

export const postReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(PostActions.successfulPostCreation, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    success: 'shared.success',
    error: undefined,
  })),
  on(PostActions.failedPostCreation, (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    success: '',
    error: payload,
  }))
);
```

post.selectors.ts

```
export const selectSuccess = createFeatureSelector<string>('success');
export const selectError = createFeatureSelector<any>('error');
```

create-post.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create',
  templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-create.component.scss'],
})
export class PostCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('form', { static: false }) form: NgForm;

  success$: Observable<string>;
  error$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private readonly notificationService: NotificationService,
    private readonly store: Store)
  {
    this.success$ = this.store.select(selectSuccess);
    this.error$ = this.store.select(selectError);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.success$.subscribe({
      next: (value) => {
        this.form.resetForm();
        this.formGroup.reset();

        this.notificationService.success(value);
      },
    });
    this.error$.subscribe({
      next: (value) => this.notificationService.error(value),
    });
  }

  submit() {
    const model { ... }

    this.store.dispatch(PostActions.createPost({ payload: model }));
  }
}
```

The process is successful, I can verify that the record is created, I can also confirm that the success property of the state is created, but the success notification message is never displayed. Debugging I managed to verify that the subscription is never invoked

I expect this to be called upon successful completion of the process.

```
    this.success$.subscribe({
      next: (value) => {
        this.form.resetForm();
        this.formGroup.reset();

        this.notificationService.success(value);
      },
    });
```

What is the reason that a subscription is not being invoked?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createFeatureSelector` are used for returning a **top** level feature state, for example, the whole `PostState` slice, you are using it for listening a particular property of `PostState`, for that, just use a simple selector, based of the feature one, for example:

```js
export const selectFeature = createFeatureSelector<PostState>('post-feature');

export const selectSuccess = createSelector(selectFeature, (state) => state.success)
```

More on selectors [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem by changing the selectors to the following

```
export const selectContent = (state: AppState) => state.content;

export const selectSuccess = createSelector(
  selectContent,
  (state: ContentState) => state.success
);
export const selectError = createSelector(
  selectContent,
  (state: ContentState) => state.error
);
```

The `AppState` looks like this

```
export interface AppState {
  post: PostState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  post: postReducer,
};

export function storageSyncReducer(
  reducer: ActionReducer<AppState>
): ActionReducer<AppState> {
  const metaReducer = storageSync<AppState>({
    features: [
      { stateKey: 'post' },
    ],
    rehydrate: true,
    storage: window.sessionStorage,
  });

  return metaReducer(reducer);
}
```

Modifying the selector resolves the issue. But I do identify that a new behavior emerges. And it is that when creating a record, the 'success' property of the reducer preserves the value, which means that when trying to register another post, the notification is not made since the value of the property `success` remains the same. In order to fix this. I have created an action that resets the status of notifications `succes` and `error` so that it is executed every time a new record is created

post.actions.ts

```
export const PostActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Create post component',
  events: {
    'Create post': props<{ payload: CreatePostModel }>(),
    'Successful post creation': emptyProps(),
    'Failed post creation': props<{ payload: any }>(),
    'Reset post notifications': emptyProps(),
  },
});
```

post.reducer.ts

```
export interface PostState {
  success: string;
  error: any;
}

export const initialState: PostState = { success: '', error: undefined };

export const contentReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(PostActions.successfulPostCreation, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    success: 'shared.success',
    error: undefined,
  })),
  on(PostActions.failedPostCreation, (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    success: '',
    error: payload,
  })),
  on(PostActions.resetPostNotifications, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    success: '',
    error: undefined,
  }))
);
```

`PostActions.resetPostNotifications` resolves the described behavior

However, there is another unexpected behavior. And it is that every time the component is loaded, it seems to subscribe and gives an error in this line

`this.form.resetForm();`

I moved the subscriptions to the AfterViewInit hook but the behavior remains. I could do a return if the value is an empty string. But it seems to me a workaround what is the correct way to handle this case?

**update-0**

Returning early if the value is an empty string does not solve the problem

Comment: Recommend using feature creators that auto create the common selectors, see https://ngrx.io/guide/store/feature-creators#using-feature-creator

Comment: I didn't know about it. Thanks for the info